# iOS - off-screen rendering using OpenGL ES2

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0, off-screen

I want to implement image edition using OpenGL shaders. I have found some examples how to implement off-screen rendering using OpenGL ES1.

Do you now any example about off-screen rendering using **OpenGL ES2** ans shaders on iPhone?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the framebuffer object extension (FBO), which is part of OpenGL ES2.

This is the same way as with OpenGL ES 1.0, except the functions lose their OES suffix (because FBO was an OES extension to ES1, not a part of the core).

You might like http://programming4.us/multimedia/3288.aspx this tutorial. The code is pretty simple and should be pretty easy to use it with GLES2.